# If Statement checking the total value of a cell range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope this makes sense. I need to write an If statement that checks the range of cells D6:D9 and check if the combined value is less than 24 if it is then i need it to print out "Fail".

How do I do this, i couldn't find the correct wording on google

Thanks
Michael

Comment: What did you try? A simple combination of IF() and SUM() should do the trick.

Comment: I have tried using countif but that hasnt worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(SUM(D6:D9)<24,"Fail","Success")
```

Comment: Ah I was so close I tried writing it like that but missed out a pair of brackets. Thank you.